# How to call PHP header refresh in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, page-refresh

I have a PHP script that does not update the page with this code in JavaScript.

```
window.onpageshow = function(event) {
    if (event.persisted) {
        window.location.reload()    
    }
};
```

The same problem occurs with [534 different ways](http://www.phpied.com/files/location-location/location-location.html) to reload a page with JavaScript.

example.php

```
<?php
header("Refresh:0");
?>
```

Any idea to let `window.location.reload()` call the file example.php?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to simulate **HTTP redirect**

```
window.location.replace("exemple.php");
```

Or this to simulate a click in a **Link**

```
window.location.href = "exemple.php";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this hack:

```
window.location.href=window.location.href
```

Comment: well its not an actual hack tbh, just a fancy way to call it that's all